# Xcode 8 GM has destroyed my UI

Tags: ios, xcode

Argh. After selecting an initial device view (6s) all my borders have completely screwed up. I used the following code:

```
func roundButtonLeft(button: UIButton) {

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:button.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topLeft, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

    let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frameLayer.path = path.cgPath
    frameLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    frameLayer.fillColor = nil

    button.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
    button.layer.mask = maskLayer}
```

which added a border on one side of my UI buttons. This doesnt work at all now and the white border shoots off the screen.

If I discard my change it works fine before I open the storyboard and get forced to select an initial device.

Can anyone help? I've wasted a few nights on this now.

Comment: are all the ui elements positioned correctly if you turn off the added borders? I had one view where all the elements were suddenly off screen after updating to XCode 8. The constraints had been incorrectly implemented - fixing that solved the issue.

Comment: all the UI Elements are correctly positioned with correct constraints as far as I can tell. If i turn off the borders the UI elements stay exactly where they are supposed to be. I should add, it is just the borders that are shooting off below the page. The UIElement is the correct size and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a long time to figure out. But it was to do with the button.bounds.

I fixed it by adding:

```
button.layoutIfNeeded()
```

before adding the Sublayer.